# error occurred while integrate opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I got an error while integrating opencv in android studio. 
My sdk version is 26

opencv versions that i have already tried : 3.1.0,3.3.0,3.2.0

when i import opencv module , gradle build but while adding module dependencies it gives the following error.

[image: my error]

opencv Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

   defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
     'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    }
    }
```

Module app:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kathirpandian.finalopencv"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
      'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
      }
     }

    dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:3.0.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
  }
```

i am trying this from last 2 days
anyone pls help to overcome this

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: I attached my gradle files

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.gradle` file in the root of your project directory you must also reference the `openCVLibrary310` module. Your `settings.gradle` file should look like this:

```
include ':app', ':openCVLibrary310'
```